# 2014 Tucson ac fan wont go to high

Tags: ac, fan

Thanks in advance. My 2014 Tucson ac fan will. Not shift in high mode. I replaced the fan which had a new resistor. I have switched the 30 amp relay still no help. Any help? Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that the fan will go at low and medium but turns off when you switch it to high?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Does this model have a switch or is it an electronically-controlled fan?

Comment: It is the ac condenser fan. It only comes on when engine is warmed up. It will not go to high when I turn on the ac. Thanks